# JavaFX: Can't unbold TableView ColumnHeader Label Text

Tags: java, css, javafx, tableview

I've been trying to get the text in all of my TableView's ColumnHeaders to unbold in javafx 8, or to say it differently, I want the font-style to be "normal". I also wanted the text to be left-aligned. In order to do that I have tried adding this line to my css

```
.table-view .column-header .label
{
    -fx-alignment: baseline-left;
    -fx-font-style: normal;
}
```

By default, the text is centered. It correctly left-aligns when I apply the above code, so I know that the block correctly refers to the elements I want to affect. The text unfortunately remains **bold**. Below is one of my tables with the css applied.

[image]

I appreciate any suggestions for how I might remove the bold quality of the text. Thanks so much for your time.

Comment: didn't try it with header but "-fx-font-weight" may be more like the correct style?

Comment: This works. I really appreciate your help. I feel silly for how simple of a oversight I've made. If you would like to answer with that information, I'll happily accept it.

Comment: @kai forgot to @ you in my last comment.

Comment: To add to what kai said, here is the [related reference](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/11/javafx.graphics/javafx/scene/doc-files/cssref.html#typefont).